# Chromium using wrong (?) srcset with sizes

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, chromium, srcset

I'm not quiet sure if it's an actual bug or if I'm just misusing srcset/sizes. We have an img tag with these properties (I removed all other properties to keep it as simple as possible, example can be found here: https://jsbin.com/sepesenodo):

- `sizes="420px"`
- `srcset="https://images.simedia.cloud/eassistant/originals/500x334/3090_30bfb97ab7a849a3896d295f0a57bbfc.jpg 500w,https://images.simedia.cloud/eassistant/originals/600x400/3090_30bfb97ab7a849a3896d295f0a57bbfc.jpg 600w"`

We have 27" monitors with a resolution of 2560x1440 and the scaling is set to 125% (inside the Windows settings).

`window.devicePixelRatio` gives 1.25 in both Firefox and Chrome/Chromium-Based Edge.

Now with the above img properties and display settings I would expect the browsers to choose the 600x400 image (width of 420px * 1.25 = 525, which means the 500x334 image would be too small). Firefox chooses the 600x400 image (showing a crisp sharp image), Chrome and Chromium-Based Edge however choose the 500x334 image, which results in a blurrish image.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug on Chrome/Chromium's side?

Comment: Note that Firefox is using dpi as if you would increase scale of all websites. To my knowledge Chrome doesn't do that. At least on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been [pointed](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1602599528472973312) [out](https://twitter.com/yoavweiss/status/1602921106096136194) on Twitter, Chrome picks the "closest" image instead of the "smallest image that's bigger" when DPR>1. This is intended behavior.

Here's a walkthrough of what's happening:

[Per spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#update-the-source-set), browsers figure out the densities of the candidates:

1. 500w/420px = 1.1904761905x
2. 600w/420px = 1.4285714286x

[The spec then gives browsers the freedom to pick whichever candidate they want](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#select-an-image-source-from-a-source-set).

Safari and Firefox choose the smallest candidate that's higher-density than the current DPR. In this case (1.25x), that's the 600w resource.

Chrome figures out which resource is "closest" by geometric mean. The distances here are:

1. 1.25x / 1.1904761905x = 1.05
2. 1.4285714286x / 1.25x = 1.1428571429

Smallest distance wins, so the first resource (500w) is chosen.